# single addEventListener with Multiple selects

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked around and I haven't really been able to find anything that solves my problem.  There is a post using buttons but I can't seem to modify it for my needs.

I am trying to use only one event listener for multiple selects.  I'd like to return the id of the select, and the value selected but as far as I can figure I either need to use  `document.getElementById("ID").addEventListener('change',func(),true)`  for each id or `document.getElementsByTagName('select').addEventListener('change', func(), true)` and I get an error that says:

`selection.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'selection.addEventListener('change', func(), true)', 'selection.addEventListener' is undefined)`

I was hoping someone could take a moment and show me where I am going wrong or if I need to use a different method to accomplish my task.

thanks for the help

Comment: You're not showing your whole code. What is `selection`?

Answer (score 0):

The method [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements, and not a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), so you can't use `addEventListener` on that.

What you can do is go over all the elements in the HTMLCollection and add the event you want to them:

```
let selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(selectElements, function(el) {
    eladdEventListener('change', func(), true)
})
```